# Displaying Magento Custom Payment Methods Form (Extension Development)

Tags: magento-1.9, extensions

I was unable to display the payment form for **"My Custom Gateway"** when the method is selected.

[image]

I have created the `form.phtml` template and it is loaded correctly. I can see the tag is loaded properly. Moreover it is visible even when I have not choose that method yet. Thus I have to hide the form until the the gateway is selected, so I have the following `form.phtml`:

```
<?php 
// PHP Code
?>
<ul class="form-list" id="mygateway_form_<?php echo $this->getMethodCode() ?>" style="display:none;">
    <li>
        <div class="input-box">
            This will be the Forms
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

In my Model, I'm extending `Mage_Payment_Model_Method_Abstract` instead of `CC`

I couldn't find any reference in the Magento source code that take care this trivial logic: hiding and showing payment form.

So, in magento, how to make my payment form visible when the user click on that particular payment methods?

### Reference List

- [Create Payment Method Module](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/5_-_modules_and_development/payment/create-payment-method-module)
- [Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30397414/764592)

Comment: https://github.com/OpenMage/magento-mirror/blob/magento-1.9/app/design/frontend/base/default/template/checkout/onepage/payment.phtml#L35-L39

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the `payment/methods.phtml`, the `input.onclick` will trigger a [`payment.switchMethod($_code)`](https://github.com/OpenMage/magento-mirror/blob/magento-1.9/app/design/frontend/base/default/template/checkout/onepage/payment/methods.phtml#L49).

Going deeper to the [`varien/payment.js:switchMethod`](https://github.com/OpenMage/magento-mirror/blob/magento-1.9/js/varien/payment.js#L48-L67) function, the naming convention is important for the form. the `id` has to begin with `payment_form_<paymentmethod>`

Thus, I've made a mistake in the `forms.phtml`. It should be:

```
<ul class="form-list" id="payment_form_<?php echo $this->getMethodCode() ?>" style="display:none;">
```

Now it is correctly display the form.